# Can I connect GNDD with GND to get stable result?

Tags: signal, signal-to-noise

[image]I am using JY-S60 Signal conditioner (SC) ([click here to see datasheet, giving amazon link, could not find specific link for datasheet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QP158YL)) with small load cell [click to see load cell datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14727). I have connected the Vo and ground of SC to Labjack U3-HV ([Click to see LabJack U3-HV datasheet](https://labjack.com/support/datasheets/u3/appendix-a)) one channel and ground for measuring  signal from small load cell (100g).

But when I check for signal, labjacks' acquired signal is not stable in 3rd decimal point which has to be stable for my experiment.

I was thinking if connecting GND(power -) and GNDD (shield) would give stable result? If I connect both ground, what exactly will happen? I do not want to damage the SC, that is why asking for help. Should I connect?

I have added schematics  for reference.

Any idea how can I stabilize the signal and read load accurately?

Comment: Links to datasheets? Schematic?

Comment: Please draw a diagram or include a schematic

Comment: Sample 10x or more and average.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should **not** connect those two points (GND and GNDD.)  That'll do you no good (though probably no harm.)

According to the Amazon page (that's **not** a datasheet,) the "GNDD" pin should be connected to the shield of the cable.

- You should use a shielded cable to connect the JY-S60 to the load cell.  Connect the GNDD pin to the shield.  Do **not** connect the shield to the ground of the load cell.  The shield should only be connected at one end.
- You should use a shielded cable to connect the JY-S60 to the Labjack U3-HV. Connect the GNDD pin to the shield.  Do **not** connect the shield to the ground of the Labjack U3-HV.  The shield should only be connected at one end.

I don't know whether that will solve your signal problems.

Comment: You need shielded cables to make use of GNDD.